# Check if value exists in JSON associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "date":"2015-07-10",
        "count":"1"
    },{
        "date":"2015-07-11",
        "count":"3"
    }
]
```

Which is given by the following Eloquent query:

```
$posts = Post::select(array(
        DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`')
    ))
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::today()->subWeek())
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

How can I check if a certain date is already in the array? I've tried the following, but it returns `false` (i.e. that the value isn't in the array, even though it is):

```
return in_array("2015-07-10", $posts);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `array_column` in this case.

```
return in_array("2015-07-10", array_column($posts, 'date'));
```

[DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: That did it, thanks! I'll mark it as the answer when I can (10 minutes).

Comment: Awesome answer!